# How to get ion-button ids in ionic with vue js?

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs3

I have 3 ion-buttons on page.

```
      <ion-button class="ion-button-1" id = "11" shape="circle" @click="SkinToneClicked($event)"></ion-button>

      <ion-button class="ion-button-2"   id = "11" shape="circle" @click="SkinToneClicked($event)"></ion-button>

      <ion-button class="ion-button-3"   id = "11" shape="circle" @click="SkinToneClicked($event)"></ion-button>
```

I want to fetch ids of all ion-buttons so that their text can be changed dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed. I have forgot to add IonButton to mypage.